# SharePoint list based on another SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a list in SharePoint that contains several fields. I need to do some calculations on this list (filter and count) and display the results on a different page. We are currently using SharePoint 2007.

I can't get what I need by creating a view from the list. I need to create a new list based on the first list to get the proper level of filtering.

The result I am trying to get from this view needs to be displayed on a separate page.

Comment: It would really help if you gave details on what filtering you require and why you need to create another list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you edited with "I need to create a new list based off the first list to get the proper level of filtering" I would suggest writing a console app with some CAML to query exactly what you need and then dump that into a new list.

However, it sounds like you could be using some calculated columns and then do what [Moo suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977253/sharepoint-list-based-on-another-sharepoint-list/977276#977276).

I think some more details about the question would help you get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the list settings, you can add filters and counts/totals/sums to the view.